# jquery width() not working with text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two containers with text in them, and I'm trying to get their widths and add them together. I've set up a jsfiddle but it doesn't seem to work at all and I'm not sure why.  I've used both width() and innerWidth().

this is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a83C6/

and this is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="text-1">hello</div>
<div class="text-2">hello</div>

<div class="length"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.length {
  border:1px solid red;
  height:5px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".length").css({
    width:$(".text-1").innerWidth() + $(".text-2").innerWidth() 
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems to work fine. Each div is taking up the full length of the page. Times two and it's what you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` is a block level element so it takes the full width of the container, so adding them together of course will have the full width of both of them doubled up, If you want to take your div's take the actual width of its content alone, you can change it to `inline-block` or `float` it and calculate the width based on that.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hf33/)**

You can do this without using JS as well,  you can add a container

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-1 text">hello</div>
    <div class="text-2 text">hello</div>
    <div class="length"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
.container, .text {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fv9gh/)**